# TextField in material ui for type=number cant accept the maxLength

Tags: material-ui

```
       <TextField
        // id="outlined-basic"
        variant="outlined"
        disabled={props.disabled}
        type={props.type}
        inputProps={{ maxLength: props.maxLength }}
        onChange={onChangeValue}
        ref={props.ref}
      />
```

Here it cant accept the maxLength why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     <TextField
        // id="outlined-basic"
        variant="outlined"
        disabled={props.disabled}
        type={props.type}
        inputProps={{ max: props.maxLength }}
        onChange={onChangeValue}
        ref={props.ref}
      />
```